# Was Einstein's riddle (the zebra puzzle) created by Albert Einstein?

Tags: history, quotes, albert-einstein, logic

I guess a lot of people have seen [this riddle](http://www.woodward.cl/engeinsteinsriddle.htm) which is commonly attributed to Einstein.  What is the true source of it and did Einstein have anything to do with it and the claim that only 2% of the people are able to solve it?

Answer (score 22):

*The Ultimate Quotable Einstein* was written by Alice Calaprice, Senior Editor and administrator of the Einstein Translation Project, who worked on all 12 volumes of his *Collected Papers*.<sup>1</sup> Though the book has an entry for the Zebra Puzzle, the attribution reads:

> Supposedly, but not actually devised by Einstein as a child.<sup>2</sup>

1. http://www.amazon.com/Alice-Calaprice/e/B001IODLOE
2. Einstein, Albert, and Alice Calaprice. *The Ultimate Quotable Einstein*. Princeton, N.J.: Princeton University Press, 2011: p. 485.

Answer (score 7):

Clue #13 is:

> The German smokes Prince.

According to Wikipedia, [Prince cigarettes were introduced in 1957](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_%28cigarette%29), 2 years after Einstein died.

Therefore, Einstein could not have written the puzzle, as he would not have heard of Prince cigarettes.

Comment: The brand is mentioned in the OP's original link. Einstein didn't create that version. QED.

Comment: @LarryOBrien If he wrote it when young, as alleged in Wikipedia, then he probably didn't write it in English either. Assuming therefore that someone translated it for a modern American readership, it's easy to imagine their changing the names of the brands.

Comment: @LarryOBrien, It's very possible for quotes to be written posthumously. E.g. someone died then someone did a biography on him.